# preg_match allowing only capital letters, numbers, space and characters(.,/-) in php

Tags: php, html

I want to match if the user input address contains capital letters, numbers, space and characters .,/- but instead it accepts all the special characters and preg_match is not being followed. Where is the error in my code and can you give me some tutorials that is easy to learn about `preg_match`? I've tried googling it but so far all I found are complex. here is my code below

```
$address = $_POST["address"];

if (!preg_match("([^A-Z0-9 ".preg_quote(".,/-")."])",$address))
{
  $addressError = "*Address contains special characters that are not allowed";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over-complicating it

```
$address = $_POST["address"];

if (!preg_match("/^[0-9A-Z .\/,-]+$/",$address))
{
  $addressError = "*Address contains special characters that are not allowed";
}
```

This is a great resource: 
https://regexr.com/

Hovering over things tells you what they do as well.

Side suggestion. You always want to give the user feedback BEFORE the form submits. So you SHOULD always verify on the backend before using the data, but doing these sort of checks within javascript or HTML5's new attribute "pattern" on the input field is suggested.

`<input type="text" name="address" id="address" pattern="[0-9A-Z ./,-] oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Address may only been digits, upper case, period, forward slash, comma and/or hyphen characters')"/>`

Comment: you need to escape the dot, as a dot means any character. And space is actually \s

Comment: Dot fixed, but no, you can use a space character itself in php regex.

Comment: I suggest you remove the trailing and leading slashes as well

Comment: Could you specify the reason?

Comment: http://pl.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php, if you'd like to submit an answer you're more than welcome to.  PHP Regex requires some sort of deliminator starting and ending the pattern.

Comment: _“you need to escape the dot, as a dot means any character”_ - only if it is outside a character class, which here it isn’t. http://pl.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php

Comment: Thank you @clearshot66 for the answer! For no reason this code is what I used when I used preg_match for the address but it didn't work at all. And regarding what you said about give the user a feedback. I make the user's input saved in the textbox if an error occurs after submitting the form. Is this a good idea or should I still give user a feedback before submitting form?